# Spring boot "build" folder not pushed to Gitlab

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have Spring boot project and pushed to Gitlab as a new project using Git commands.

```
git remote add origin <gitlab path>
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push
```

Successfully pushed to Gitlab.
I am trying to run Git command in CICD pipeline to build my code. Then, I found Git pipeline failed with `chmod: cannot access 'build': No such file or directory`
Because, when i pushed project from local to Gitlab, i didn't see `"build"` folder also pushed to Gitlab, i am not sure why. Could you please tell me, why the `"build"` folder didn't pushed to Gitlab and how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

No "Build" pushed to Gitlab screenshot ref:

[image]

gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  image: gradle:jdk17
  services:
      - docker:dind # use the docker-in-docker image
  before_script: # install docker
      - apt update && apt install --no-install-recommends -y docker.io
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - echo "Compile complete."
    - chmod +x ./gradlew build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./build/libs/
```

.gitignore:

```
HELP.md
.gradle
build/
!gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
!**/src/main/**/build/
!**/src/test/**/build/

### STS ###
.apt_generated
.classpath
.factorypath
.project
.settings
.springBeans
.sts4-cache
bin/
!**/src/main/**/bin/
!**/src/test/**/bin/

### IntelliJ IDEA ###
.idea
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr
out/
!**/src/main/**/out/
!**/src/test/**/out/

### NetBeans ###
/nbproject/private/
/nbbuild/
/dist/
/nbdist/
/.nb-gradle/

### VS Code ###
.vscode/
```

Comment: Is that directory in your `.gitignore` ?

Comment: Hi @sytech Yes, i updated gitignore above. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have included `build/` in the `.gitignore` file. Remove it from there to track it to git repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.gitignore` contains a line that prevents you from adding your `build` directory when you do `git add .` -- remove the line from your `.gitignore` that is ignoring the `build` directory.

Alternatively, you can add it explicitly, even if it is in your `.gitignore`:

```
git add ./build
git commit -m "add build"
git push
```

Though, assuming your `build/` directory is for the output of your build process, you usually don't need to commit your this directory (which is probably why it is in your `.gitignore` to begin with). You can just make your gitlab job run the build process to produce the build output (usually a build task defined in your gradle build file).

```
script:
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  - ./gradlew build
```

Comment: I just tried, keeping build/ directory in .gitignore. Update script:
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  - ./gradlew build in gitlab.yml and pushed the Gitlab. What happens is, it is creating "build" folder, but no "libs" subfolder or any subfolders to have .jar file.